# Question about transversal subvarieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> **Definition:** Subvarieties $ Y_{1},\dots,Y_{r} $ of a nonsingular variety $ X $ are transversal at a point $ x  = \bigcap Y_{i} $ if $$ \text{codim}_{\Theta_{X,x}}\Bigg(\bigcap_{i=1}^{r} \Theta_{Y_{i},x} \Bigg) = \sum_{i=1}^{r} \text{codim}_{X}Y_{i}. $$

The author proceeds to say:

> Two curves on a nonsingular surface are transversal at a point of intersection if they are both nonsingular and their tangent lines are different.

How can I deduce this from the definition?

In a previous section, the author states that:

> $$ \text{codim}_{X}\Bigg(\bigcap_{i=1}^{r} Y_{i} \Bigg) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{r} \text{codim}_{X}Y_{i}. $$

If we apply this inequality to the subspaces $ \Theta_{Y_{i},x} \subset \Theta_{X,x}, $ we have $$ \text{codim}_{\Theta_{X,x}}\Bigg(\bigcap_{i=1}^{r} \Theta_{Y_{i},x} \Bigg) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{r} \text{codim}_{\Theta_{X,x}}\Theta_{Y_{i},x}. $$

Furthermore, if we recall the fact that $ \text{codim}\Theta_{Y_{i},x} \leq \text{codim}_{X}Y_{i}, $ the very first equation (in the definition) implies that $$ \text{dim}\Theta_{Y_{i},x} = \text{dim}Y_{i}. $$

I am struggling to make this last deduction. Why do these facts imply that $ \text{dim}\Theta_{Y_{i},x} = \text{dim}Y_{i}$  ?

Comment: What is $\Theta_{Y,x}$?

Comment: @KReiser The tangent space to $ Y $ at $ x. $

Comment: Remember that the (co)tangent space at a nonsingular point is the same dimension as the variety is at that point. When you apply it to your scenario, you'll get the LHS of your definition is 2, since the intersection is a point in a 2-d vector space, while the RHS is 2=1+1, as a curve inside a surface is codimension 1. This shows that your situation satisfies the definition.

Comment: @KReiser I know that in general, the (co)tangent space at a nonsingular point is the same dimension as the variety is at that point, and I saw what the dimensions on either side of the definition would be. I think the part that confuses me is in what sense the "tangent lines are different." But on reflection, it seems that was meant literally and it makes sense. As far as the second question, I guess I was trying to make the deduction that $ \text{dim}\Theta_{Y_{i},x} = \text{dim}Y_{i} $ purely with the inequalities they gave.

Comment: The RHS of the equality is 2, since these are curves on a surface. Now is if one of the curves say $Y_1$ is singular at the point of intersection say $p$, then at that point $dim(\Theta_{Y_1, p}) > dim(Y_1) = 1$. This implies that $dim(\Theta_{Y_1, p}) = 2$ and hence $\Theta_{Y_1, p} = \Theta_{X, p}$. Now, note that $\Theta_{Y_1, p} \cap \Theta_{Y_2, p} = \Theta_{Y_2, p}$, which is atleast one dimensional, and hence can have codimension atmost 1. A contradiction. Hence the assumption that either of the curves were singular at the point of transversal intersection is false.